# recurrence relation for this n queen problem algorithm . and the time complexity

Tags: time-complexity, algorithm-analysis, backtracking

I am not able to understand how to write a recurrence relation for this n queen problem algorithm down below.    Recurrence relation is for n*n board and the time complexity

```
Algorithm : nQueen(B) for the n queens problem
Input : 2-dimensional array B[]

Output: All solutions B[] satisfying the condition for the eight queens problem

1 for i ← 1, 2,..., n do
2      for j ← 1, 2,..., n do
3            B[i, j] ← 0 ; /* Initialize the board */
4      end
5 end

6 for i ← 1, 2,..., n do
7     B[i, 1] ← 1 ; /* Put the first queen at B(1, j) */
8     QueenSub(B, 2) ; /* Proceed to the second column */
9     B[i, 1] ← 0 ; /* Remove the first queen from B(1, j) */
10 end

Algorithm : Subroutine QueenSub(B,J)


Input : 2-dimensional array B[], the number i of column
 Output: Each B[] that satisfies the conditions of the eight queens problem

1   for I ← 1, 2,..., N do
2       c ← 0 ; /* The number of threatening queens */
3     for k = 1,...,J − 1 do
4        if i − (j − k) > 0 then /* Queens on the left upper diagonal? */
5            c ← c + B[ i − (j − k),k]; 
6        end
7        c ← c + B[i,k] ; /* Queens on the left of B(i, j)? */
8        if i + (j − k)) < 9 then /* Queens on the left lower diagonal? */
9           c ← c + B[i + (j − k), k];
10        end
11     end
12     if c = 0 then /* No queen threatening here */
13           B[i, j] ← 1 ; /* Put a queen at B(i, j) */
14           if i = n then /* The last column? */
15              output B[] ; /* This is a solution */
16           else
17             QueenSub(B,j + 1) ; /* Proceed to the next column */
18            end
19            B[i, j] ← 0 ; /* Remove the queen from B(i, j) */
20       end
21   end
```

:

Comment: You should decide whether you want to solve 8 queens or n queens. For the n queens problem, just replace the 9 with n+1 in your algorithm. For the 8 queens problem, set n = 8 and the time complexity is O(1) because the number of operations is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm basically does this:

```
for all positions in row 1
  for all positions in row 2 without conflict with row 1
    for all positions in row 3 without conflict with rows 1-2
      for all positions in row 4 without conflict with rows 1-3
```

etc. The time complexity is difficult, because it depends on the actual number of conflicts which is hard to estimate. An upper bound is O (n!), a lower bound is n(n-3)(n-6)(n-9) ... = (n/3)! * 3^(n/3), because each row can only produce 3 conflicts.

Your test whether a position is conflict free takes O(n) steps, which isn't necessary, so the time complexity is (number of conflict free positions) * n.

You have conflicts because of queens moving straight up, diagonally to the left, and diagonally to the right. Maintain three bit masks for the straight up lines, left diagonals, and right diagonals hitting row i. These bit masks are empty for the first row. Conflict free positions are those in none of the three masks. If you decide to put a queen into position j in row i, set bit #j in each mask, then shift the "left diagonal" mask one position to the left, and shift the "right diagonal mask" one position to the right. This saves a factor O(n) and should give a very small constant factor.

The time complexity of finding or counting all solutions seems to grow extremely fast. The time complexity of finding *one* solution seems to grow a lot slower, but still fast.

Comment: i think that my algo works column by column instead of row by row it checks the rows in every column & it put the queen on the jth column in the i th row

Comment: What’s the difference?